# Converting webpages having lazy loading elements to pdf

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation, lazy-loading, html-to-pdf

I need to convert a webpage which has a number of images in lazy loading form. I need to convert that webpage into pdf. The different online converters I tried could not convert the image which were in lazy loading format. Is there any web app or any standalone application which will do the work?

Comment: Use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/index.html) optionally with [this flag `--javascript-delay <msec>`](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt).

Comment: @insertusernamehere I tried using it but it is not giving the desired results. The webpage I am trying to convert has images in the "img" class with "data-lazy-src" as the attribute

Comment: Most likely in wkhtmltopdf it's necessary to scroll pages down using javascript to trigger loading of full images, something like flags `--javascript-delay 2000 --run-script "javascript:(function a(){var b=document.body.scrollTop+document.body.clientHeight;if(b<document.body.scrollHeight){window.scrollTo(0,b);setTimeout(a,200)}}a())"`